# Does webview2 in winui3 not support changing the download location?

Tags: c#, .net, winui-3, webview2

I used cefsharp, I need to generate folders according to certain rules and download the web content to the specified directory. I'm going to replace it with webview2. I find that there is no way to specify the default download directory. Do you have any way?

Comment: If you mean the HTTP cache and all other storage then see the answer below about the User Data Folder. If you mean specifically the browser download feature, you can change where downloads will be stored on disk via the `CoreWebView2.DownloadStarting` event's `ResultFilePath` property https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/winrt/microsoft_web_webview2_core/corewebview2downloadstartingeventargs?view=webview2-winrt-1.0.1418.22#resultfilepath

Answer (score 0):

It may evolve in the future, but currently, you must define the `WEBVIEW2_USER_DATA_FOLDER` environment variable manually as explained here [WebView2 Globals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/webview2-idl), something like this:

```
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("WEBVIEW2_USER_DATA_FOLDER", @"c:\temp\mydata");
        MyWebView.CoreWebView2Initialized += MyWebView_CoreWebView2Initialized;
    }

    private void MyWebView_CoreWebView2Initialized(WebView2 sender, CoreWebView2InitializedEventArgs args)
    {
        // udf will contain c:\temp\mydata
        var udf = sender.CoreWebView2.Environment.UserDataFolder;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I set WEBVIEW2_ USER_ DATA_ FOLDER is invalid.

Comment: and Environment.UserDataFolder is inconsistent with the actual download path